# Sorting global data alphbetically

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am storing the parsed xml values as Global data in Mutable Array some thing like this...

.h file

```
@interface GlobalData : NSObject {

NSMutableArray *array;
```

}

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *array;

- (id)sharedData;

In .m file

```
static GlobalData *sharedGlobalData = nil;
```

@implementation GlobalData

@synthesize array;

+(id)sharedData{

```
@synchronized(self) {
    if(sharedGlobalData == nil)
    {
        sharedGlobalData=[[GlobalData alloc] init];
        sharedGlobalData.boats=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    }
}
return sharedGlobalData;
```

}

- (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
  @synchronized(self) {
      if(sharedGlobalData == nil)  {
          sharedGlobalData = [super allocWithZone:zone];
          return sharedGlobalData;
      }
  }
  return nil;
  }

I am passing the value of array to a Table view and displaying it as a table. Now i want to sort this array alphbetically from A-Z and pass it to table view.How can i do this???... Plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it by using NSSortDescriptor....

something like this,

```
    NSSortDescriptor *alphaDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"boatName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    [[data boats] sortUsingDescriptors:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:alphaDesc, nil]];
```